# How to write condition along with the ContainingIgnoreCase in Spring Data JPA

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am trying to fetch all the rows where deletedAt fields are null. But it's not working.

```
List<DesignTeam> findByDesignTeamContainingIgnoreCaseOrDesignCodeContainingIgnoreCaseAndDeletedAtNullOrderByIdDesc(String search, String s, Pageable pageable);
```

Comment: How does the genererated SQL look like?

Comment: select * from designTeam where deleted_at is null and (design_team like '%params%' or design_code like '%param2%' orderBy id desc limit 0 offset 10;

Comment: And this is not what you want?

Comment: Yes! But I want to write ***findByDesignTeamContainingIgnoreCaseOrDesignCodeContainingIgnoreCaseAndDeletedAtNullOrderByIdDesc*** in this way.